# Run a script file for font generation

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, fonts

In the EB-Garamond github [repository](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond) there's a makefile, which is supposed to generate the Garamond font files. Here are the first lines of the file:

```
NAME=EBGaramond
VERSION=0.016

SRC=SFD
BLD=build
WEB=web
SPEC=specimen
PACK=$(NAME)-$(VERSION)
WPCK=$(NAME)-$(VERSION)-web
DIST=$(NAME)-$(VERSION)-complete

#Call script through fontforge, not python. https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/528
FF=fontforge
#Return to python because we don’t scale the font any longer.
PYTHON?=python
SCRIPT=tools/makefont.py

#SIZES=08 12
#STYLES=Regular SC Allsc Italic Bold
#SPECIAL=Initials InitialsF1 InitialsF2
FONTS=08-Regular 08-Italic 12-Regular SC12-Regular 12-AllSC 12-Italic  -Initials -InitialsF1 -InitialsF2 SC08-Regular # SC12-Italic 12-Bold

SFD=$(FONTS:%=$(SRC)/$(NAME)%.sfdir)
OTF=$(FONTS:%=$(BLD)/$(NAME)%.otf)
TTF=$(FONTS:%=$(BLD)/$(NAME)%.ttf)
WOF=$(FONTS:%=$(WEB)/$(NAME)%.woff)
PDF=$(FONTS:%=$(SPEC)/$(NAME)%-Glyphs.pdf)

all: otf ttf webfonts # pdfs
pack: dpack wpack

otf: $(OTF)
ttf: $(TTF)
webfonts: $(WOF)
pdfs: $(PDF)

$(BLD):
    @mkdir $@
$(WEB):
    @mkdir -p $@
$(SPEC):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(BLD)/%.otf: $(SRC)/%.sfdir Makefile $(SCRIPT) | $(BLD)
    @echo "Generating   $@"
    @$(PYTHON) $(SCRIPT) $< $@ $(VERSION)
```

How should I run it?  I don't know what script language it is. I tried with python and fontforge, but they don't seem to recognise the file.

Comment: It's a `makefile` -- you've already tagged it as such.  Just run `make` in the directory containing the file.

Comment: @G.M.  Thank you!  Sorry for the stupid question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make sure you have a version of the `make` command line utility installed on your system, and then run `make`.